# Pyglet: GluProject() gives double coordinates

Tags: python, pyglet

I am making a basic planetary position tracker with python, like Stellarium. I have programmed it to show the positions of the moon and all of the other solar system's planets. But, the labels show at opposite coordinates too:

[image: Output]

Here you can see the wrong position of the `Mars` label.

This is the code for the application:

main.py

```
import logger as logger
import json
import skyfield
# load config
with open('config.json') as json_file:
    config = json.load(json_file)
if config['dev_mode']:
    logger.warn("StarHunter", "Running in dev mode")

logger.info('StarHunter', "Initialising...")

import planetary_locations

import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import math
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=800, height=600, resizable=True, caption="StarHunter")
locator = planetary_locations.PlanetLocator(logger, window)

camrot = [0, 0]
zoom = 1
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
glCullFace(GL_BACK)
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0)

def _setup_3d():
    w, h = window.width, window.height

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(70-zoom, w / h, 0.1, 1000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    _setup_3d()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    locator.camrot = camrot

    _setup_3d()
    glRotatef(camrot[0], 1, 0, 0)
    glRotatef(camrot[1], 0, 1, 0)
    glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1)

    locator.draw()

@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
    global camrot
    camrot[1] -= dx / 4
    camrot[0] += dy / 4

# scroll to zoom
@window.event
def on_mouse_scroll(x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y):
    # change fov
    global zoom
    zoom += scroll_y
    if zoom <= 0:
        zoom = 1
    elif zoom >= 60:
        zoom = 60

    locator.set_zoom(zoom)

pyglet.app.run()
```

planetary_locations.py

```
# get location of mars in the sky
from skyfield.api import load
from pyglet.gl import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import math

def cart2sphere(x, y, z):
    r = (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5
    phi = math.atan2(y, x)
    theta = math.acos(z / r)
    return r, phi, theta

def sphere2cart(r, phi, theta):
    x = r * math.sin(theta) * math.cos(phi)
    y = r * math.sin(theta) * math.sin(phi)
    z = r * math.cos(theta)
    return x, y, z

def _setup_3d(window, zoom):
    w, h = window.width, window.height

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(70-zoom, w / h, 0.1, 1000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def _setup_2d(window):
    w, h = window.width, window.height
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluOrtho2D(0, w, h, 0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    # upside down
    glRotatef(180, 1, 0, 0)

class PlanetLocator:
    def __init__(self, logger, window):
        self.logger = logger
        self.window = window

        self.ts = load.timescale()
        self.t = self.ts.now()
        self.planets = load('de421.bsp')

        self.sun = self.planets['sun']
        self.earth = self.planets['earth']
        self.moon = self.planets['moon']

        self.mercury = self.planets['mercury']
        self.venus = self.planets['venus']
        self.mars = self.planets['mars']
        self.jupiter = self.planets['Jupiter barycenter']
        self.saturn = self.planets['saturn barycenter']
        self.uranus = self.planets['uranus barycenter']
        self.neptune = self.planets['neptune barycenter']
        self.w = self.window.width
        self.zoom = 1
        self.camrot = [0, 0]

        self.labels = {}

    def _draw(self, planet, name, color, size):
        if not name in self.labels:
            label = pyglet.text.Label(text=name, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center', font_size=20-self.zoom/10, color=(255, 255, 255, 255))
            self.labels[name] = label
        self.ts = load.timescale()
        self.t = self.ts.now()
        glPushMatrix()
        observation = self.earth.at(self.t).observe(planet).apparent().radec()
        _, __, ___ = 400, observation[0]._degrees, observation[1]._degrees
        x, y, z = sphere2cart(_, __, ___)
        
        glTranslatef(x, y, z)
        glColor3f(*color)
        gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), size/10, 10, 10)
        
        # Get this point's 2d coordinates on the screen
        pos = gluProject(0, 0, 0)
        glPushMatrix()
        _setup_2d(self.window)
        self.labels[name].x = pos[0]
        self.labels[name].y = pos[1] - self.w / 4 * 3 + self.zoom / 10 + 30
        self.labels[name].draw()
        _setup_3d(self.window, self.zoom)
        glPopMatrix()
        glPopMatrix()
        
    def draw(self):
        self._draw(self.sun, 'Sun', (1, 1, 0), 80)
        self._draw(self.moon, 'Moon', (1, 1, 1), 80)
        self._draw(self.mercury, 'Mercury', (1, 0, 0), 30)
        self._draw(self.venus, 'Venus', (1, 0, 0), 40)
        self._draw(self.mars, 'Mars', (1, 0, 0), 35)
        self._draw(self.jupiter, 'Jupiter', (1, 0, 0), 40)
        self._draw(self.saturn, 'Saturn', (1, 0, 0), 38)
        self._draw(self.uranus, 'Uranus', (0, 0, 1), 36)
        self._draw(self.neptune, 'Neptune', (0, 0, 1), 36)

    def set_zoom(self, zoom):
        self.zoom = zoom
```

So the question is, is there any other way to create labels which follow 3d objects, or to fix the issue using the same approach?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing duplicates is because of this line.

```
pyglet.text.Label(text=name, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center', font_size=20-self.zoom/10, color=(255, 255, 255, 255), x=pos[0], y=pos[1] - self.w / 4 * 3 + self.zoom / 10 + 30).draw()
```

This line is actually creating a new label every time it's run.

You need to create your labels during initialization, then use those to draw.

Do this during initialization somewhere for your labels:

```
self.sun_label = pyglet.text.Label(text="Sun", anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center', font_size=20-self.zoom/10, color=(255, 255, 255, 255), x=pos[0], y=pos[1] - self.w / 4 * 3 + self.zoom / 10 + 30)
```

Then during draw:

```
self.sun_label.draw()
```

You can also update the position of the label by doing.`self.sun_label.position = new_pos`

You would also benefit from using a camera to handle the the view position and zooming instead of updating positions constantly.

Comment: I tried that and edited the question, but it still gives the same output. Maybe something to do with the GluProject or the cart2sphere function.

Comment: I am not too familiar with 3D unfortunately. I would try commenting out some of the 3D stuff, and add it back 1 piece at a time until the problem starts occurring.